# Conditionals in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have predicates `monthyear` that returns the current month if month and year are not supplied below.

```
monthyear(M,Y) :-
    get_time(Stamp),
    stamp_date_time(Stamp, DateTime, local),
    date_time_value(month, DateTime, M),
    date_time_value(year, DateTime, Y).
```

If month and year are supplied return supplied month and year.
To achieve this i have written the following code below.

```
cal(X,Y,Z1,Z2):-
    Z1 is X,
    Z2 is Y.

cal(X,Y,Z1,Z2):-
    X == null,
    Y == null,
    monthyear(Z1,Z2).
```

However i am sure this code can be improved and i am also faced with an error

```
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

How can i go about making this work?.

```
X=1,Y=2,cal(X,Y,Z1,Z2).
returns
Z1 = X
Z2 = Y
```

and

```
cal(X,Y,Z1,Z2).
returns
Z1 = 1,
Z2 = 2016
```

Comment: `== null`? What do you mean with `== null`?

Comment: Furthermore please provide the query, and examples. It is a bit unclear to me what you want to achieve...

Comment: that means that if values of X and Y are not supplied by a parent predicate.

Comment: That's not how this is done in Prolog... Mind Prolog is a logic programming languages, that's quite different compared to an imperative one like Java.

Comment: thats where i need help. Having a hard time. I have edited the question. Hope it makes it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two versions of `cal`:

```
cal(X,Y,Z1,Z2):-
    Z1 is X,
    Z2 is Y.

cal(Z1,Z2):-
    monthyear(Z1,Z2).
```

If you call `cal(2, 2015, Z1, Z2)` you will get

```
Z1 = 2,
Z2 = 2015.
```

If you call `cal(Z1, Z2)` you will get (today)

```
Z1 = 1,
Z2 = 2016.
```